# SmartGWT Live Grid (with iBATIS)

Tags: gwt, ibatis, smartclient

I didn't find any docs about how to convert a SmartGWT ListGrid in a Live Grid. How can I do it? Is the ListGrid a Live Grid by default? If so, how can I disable this feature?

Finally: I have to provide a DataSource for the Grid. My app uses iBATIS in the server-side, using GWT-RPC. How can I provide the data to the Live Grid and let it manage the data to be fetched?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change anything on your ListGrid, your DataSource which is bound to your ListGrid has to send the startrow and endrow parameter and then your backend has to return the appropriate data.
You can the see if the parameters are send in firebug, if they aren't send, just call setSendMetaData(true) on your DataSource

I don't have any knowledge with iBatis so I can't answers that part of the questions